# HTML canvas only triggered after browser resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've a nice bit of JS that creates falling confetti using the HTML `canvas` -- but it only starts drawing if you resize the browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/pmfgexfL/

Before resize:
[image]

After resize:
[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Your `window.w = 0; window.h = 0;` at init cause the cofetti always draw at `(0, 0)` until resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your canvas width is only set inside the `resizeWindow();` function.

Try adding `resizeWindow();` directly after the function definition:

```
resizeWindow = function() {
    window.w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    return window.h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

resizeWindow();
```

otherwise it doesn't get called until the page is resized.

http://jsfiddle.net/pmfgexfL/3/

Your `window.onload` won't get called because it is inside `confetti()`.

**EDIT:** As fuyushimoya pointed out, also remove the `window.w = 0;` and `window.h = 0;` lines since they're not required. I think that it is actually cleaner to set the size in a function on resize (as you do) in case you want to do something more custom, but you need to call it to initialize too.

http://jsfiddle.net/pmfgexfL/5/

Comment: I believe you can also just trigger the actual `window.resize` event `window.fireEvent('resize')` ex

Comment: True, although I imagine that there would be less overhead by calling it directly.

Answer (score 1):

At initialization, you have:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("world");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.w = 0;
window.h = 0;
```

which makes `w` and `h` for cofettis becomes (0, 0). It cause your `Confetti.prototype.replace` to have useless `xmax` and `ymax`:

```
Confetti.prototype.replace = function() {
    this.opacity = 0;
    this.dop = 0.03 * range(1, 4);
    this.x = range(-this.r2, w - this.r2);
    this.y = range(-20, h - this.r2);
    this.xmax = w - this.r;  // -2 ~ -6
    this.ymax = h - this.r;  // -2 ~ -6
    this.vx = range(0, 2) + 8 * xpos - 5;
    return this.vy = 0.7 * this.r + range(-1, 1);
};
```

These makes its `draw` function unable to draw something properly, as x and y would be invalid when `x` or `y` is greater that `0`.

Change it to

```
canvas = document.getElementById("world");

context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Init the width and height of the canvas, and the global w and h.
window.w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
window.h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

See [Altered Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmfgexfL/6/).